# How to crawl latest articles in a specific site using specific set keyword?

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying a python code for crawling article links on specific sites based on key word like name of the article.but i didn't get the links  appropriate links.

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urlparse import urlparse
def extract_article_links(url,data):
    req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    responseData = response.read()
    #r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(responseData.content)
    links = soup.find_all('a')
    for link in links:
       try:
            #if 'http' in link:
            print ("<a href='%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get('href'),link.text))
       except Exception as e :
            print (e)
    responseData = soup.find_all("div",{"class:info"})
    print responseData
    for item in responseData:
        print (item.contents[0].text)
        print (item.contents[1].text)
    if __name__ == "__main__":
       from sys import argv
       if (len(argv)<2):
          print"Insufficient arguments..!!"
          sys.exit(1)
        url = sys.argv[1]
        values = {'s':'article','submit':'search'}
        data = urlparse.urlencode(values)
        data = data.encode('utf-8')
        extract_article_links(url,data)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try [lxml](http://lxml.de/), analyze the html and locate elements you are looking for, then you can do this easily with xpath :

```
from lxml import html
print map (lambda link: link, html.fromstring(source).xpath('//a/@href'))
```

of course you need to modify the xpath according to the attribute you are looking for.

Comment: yes i ried this but issue i didin't found the exact latest links that i am tring to crawl

Comment: hey take newspaper link for example hindustantimes.com and i need to find articles related to particular exams information

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract_article_links(url,data):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.hindustantimes.com/Search/search.aspx?q={}&op=All&pt=all&auth=all'.format(data)).content)
    responseData = soup.find("ul",{'class':'searchNews'}) 
    _a, _li = responseData.find_all('a'), responseData.find_all('li')
    for i,j in zip(_a,_li):
        print '='*40,'\nLink: ',i['href'], '\nTitle: ',i.contents[0], '\nContent: \n\t', j.p.get_text(),'\n'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://www.hindustantimes.com/"
    extract_article_links(url,'article')
```

Comment: hey  its working,Thanks...but can we generalize this?

Comment: now showing all the links on the page after search for article.

Comment: What do you mean by generalizing it ?

Comment: Done With the Code.Thanks.I mean For all newspaper the search source will be different ,so want generalize it

Comment: Of course they'll be different, therefor there is no generalized solution. You can either extract the layout of various newspapers and modify the code accordingly or go the real way and learn about machine learning. By using that you can generalize this process by learning about new structures through a technique called Tree matching, it is not easy though. but your software will learn more and more as you do this process. You should search for it in topics related to Web mining and data extraction.